# Perl takes a long time to evaluate: keys %hash / iterate through a large hash

Tags: perl, hash, hashmap

In a Perl script, I build up a large hash (around 10 GB) which takes about 40 minuets, which has around 100 million keys. Next I want to loop through the keys of the hash, like so:

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
```

However this lines takes 1 hour and 20 minuets to evaluate! Once in the for-loop the code runs through the whole hash at a quick pace.

Why does entering the forloop take so long? And how can I speed the process up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
```

This code will create a list that includes all the keys in `%hash` first, and you said your `%hash` is huge, then that will take a while to finish. Especially if you start swapping memory to disk because you ran out of real memory.

You could use `while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash) {` to iterate over that hash, and this one will not create that huge list. If you were swapping, this will be *much* faster since you won't be anymore.

Comment: Amazing! Before my script took 2 hours to run and now it take 8 minuets!! thanks

Comment: Made some small clarifying changes.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for your improvements.

Comment: This is one of those rare occasions when it is considered acceptable to use `each()` on a hash. Though it might be good to put some big warning comments in there explaining why, and drawing attention to its subtle nature in case of future editors.

Answer (score 7):

There are two approaches to iterate over hash, both having their pros and cons.

#### Approach 1:

```
foreach my $k (keys %h)
{
  print "key: $k, value: $h{$k}\n";
}
```

#### Pros:

- It is possible to sort the output by key.

#### Cons:

- It creates a temporary list to hold the keys, in case your hash is very large you end up using lots of memory resources.

---

#### Approach 2:

```
while ( ($k, $v) = each %h )
{
  print "key: $k, value: $h{$k}\n";
}
```

#### Pros:

- This uses very little memory as every time `each` is called it only returns a pair of (key, value) element.

#### Cons:

- You can't order the output by key.
- The iterator it uses belongs to `%h`. If the code inside the loop calls something that does `keys %h`, `values %h` or `each %h`, then the loop won't work properly, because `%h` only has 1 iterator

Comment: Another con to using `each` is that the iterator it uses belongs to `%h`.  If the code inside the loop calls something that does `keys %h`, `values %h` or `each %h`, then the loop won't work properly, because `%h` only has 1 iterator.

Comment: Thanks @cjm. Great, I didnt know that. Will add to the answer. Appreciate it.

Comment: Yep this was the problem. Cheers for the clear answer!